# can locals be passed two levels in rails views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I am having an issue passing a :locals variable to two levels of views. Normally, I just use one and am just wondering if there is something that prevents this:

For example:

```
<%=render :partial => 'shared/following', :locals => {:following => @following} %>
```

in shared/_following.html.erb (assuming item is of type 'Location'):

```
<% following.each do |item| %>
   <% class_type=item.class.to_s %>
  <%#works fine %> 
  <%=debug(item) %>
  <%# a bunch of different types of things to follow %>
  <%=render 'shared/box-'+class_type.downcase! , :locals => { :item => item } %>
<% end %>
```

in shared/_box-location.html.erb:

```
<% # this doesn't work nor does @item.name %>
<%=item.name %>
```

Can I do locals two levels deep? How can I / should I rectify?

thx

Comment: You might not need the 'shared' in the second partial call since you're already within the shared directory. Have you tried just displaying html (sans the item) at the second level to see if it even renders?

Comment: yeah, I put some html in there that renders fine. when I `<%=debug(item) %>` I get an error. The only thing that gives me somewhat of a positive answer is `<%=debug(@item) %>` which gives me null but at the first level, the information is there. I'm sure this is something so simple. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also note that explicitly specifying :partial is required when passing
>   additional options such as :layout.

([Source](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials))

`:locals` is also an additional option, so try this:

```
<%= render :partial => 'shared/box-'+class_type.downcase!, :locals => { :item => item } %>
```

Comment: There are two other short forms you can use that don't require `:partial` -- (1) `render :partial => 'item', :object => @item` can be shortened to `render @item` (2) `render :partial => 'item_selector', :locals => { :item => item }` can be shortened to `render 'item_selector', :item => item`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either

```
<%=render :partial => 'shared/box-'+class_type.downcase! , :locals => { :item => item } %>
```

or

```
<%=render 'shared/box-'+class_type.downcase! , :item => item %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this, make shared/box to be partial.

```
<%=render :partial =>'shared/box-'+class_type.downcase! , :locals => { :item => item } %>
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime back I faced the same issue. I just added ":partial" and after that it worked. Try this.

```
<%=render :partial => 'shared/box-'+class_type.downcase! , :locals => { :item => item } %>
```